# C-style string deallocation

Tags: c++, c, string

Why people do not deallocate c-style strings?

```
const char* string = "Whatever";
```

And how does it work actually, because there is no some kind of `new` or `malloc`?

Comment: There is symmetry in nature. You only deallocate what you allocated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the given string there is no memory allocation on the heap.

An array of chars `"Whatever"` is created in the *const* section. The address of this array is given to the pointer `string`